# Most efficient way to calculate VWAP(VOLUME WEIGHTED AVERAGE PRICE) for trading algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, trading, tradingview-api

I am looking for an efficient VWAP algorithm for a dataframe that contains 5 minute candles data for a stock for an year.

My code:

```
def calculate_vwap(data):
    data['VWAP'] = data.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: ((x['high'] + x['low'] + x['close']) / 3 * x['volume']).cumsum() / x['volume'].cumsum()).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    return data['VWAP']
```

The output of my code does not match tradingview VWAP values. Link to the sample data -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12oDiWe9HWQDZEvGmQAqcznklT8NBObGQ/view?usp=sharing
Sample:

[image: stock dataframe]

Comment: Can you post some sample data and a [mcve]? Also, is your complaint that your code takes too long, or that it doesn't match what you see in another tool?

Comment: Thanks @Carbon Here is the link to a sample data. Slowness is not an issue at this point. I am more concerned with accuracy of VWAP and that i should match with TradingView platform data

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/12oDiWe9HWQDZEvGmQAqcznklT8NBObGQ/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I found out that some trading platforms use this average price - (high+low+close)/3 and some use (high+low)/2 for arriving at VWAP values.

And also for the VWAP calculation the cumulataive volume and cumulative (priceXvolume) is calculated from first candle of the day. This lead me to modify my codes like this and it worked now -

```
for ticker in Angel_Hist_Data5Min:

Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["AvgP"] = ((Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["high"]+Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["low"]+Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["close"])/3)
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["PV"] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["AvgP"]*Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["volume"]
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]['CumPV'] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker].groupby(Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]['date'].dt.date)['PV'].cumsum()
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["VWAP_hlc"] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["CumPV"]/Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["CumVolume"] 

Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["AvgP_hl"] = ((Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["high"]+Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["low"])/2)
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["PV_hl"] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["AvgP_hl"]*Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["volume"]  
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]['CumPV_hl'] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker].groupby(Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]['date'].dt.date)['PV_hl'].cumsum()
Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["VWAP_hl"] = Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["CumPV_hl"]/Angel_Hist_Data5Min[ticker]["CumVolume"]
```

I am calculating two VWAPs now and this helps to match with all the trading platforms data.

Comment: A small modification to @shri answer

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to get the TradingView VWAP:`symbol = "HDFCBANK-EQ"
df_1min = pd.read_csv(f'Data/1/{symbol}.csv', index_col=False)
df_1min['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1min['DT'])

```
# Calculate VWAP using the average of high, low, and close prices
df_1min["AvgP"] = (df_1min["High"] + df_1min["Low"] + df_1min["Close"]) / 3
df_1min["PV"] = df_1min["AvgP"] * df_1min["Volume"]

# Group by date and calculate cumulative volume and cumulative PV
grouped = df_1min.groupby(df_1min['DT'].dt.date)
df_1min['CumVolume'] = grouped['Volume'].cumsum()
df_1min['CumPV'] = grouped['PV'].cumsum()

# Calculate VWAP using cumulative values until that time
df_1min["VWAP"] = df_1min["CumPV"] / df_1min["CumVolume"]`
```